# What i need to install on client pc for my .mdf database to work?

Tags: sql, mdf

I developed an application in vs 2008, C#. Added the database in the project with `add -> new item`.
(using SQL Server 2005)

I took the connection string from `app.config`:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Baza.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

I tried and installed SQL Server 2005 Express on a test client machine, and it worked fine.. But is there a better solution? Or it is a good and safe way to install my app on client pc's?

Edit: 
Also, I am planing in the future to make my application to be used in a network (local), is there like a instruction/directions on how to manage this? (how to make my database to work in a network)..

Comment: If you're using a `.mdf` file - you're using SQL Server. And in order to use SQL Server, you have to have a SQL Server instance running somewhere in the customer's LAN - on individual machines, or on a central server. There is no "better way" to do this - this is the **only** way to use SQL Server database files. SQL Server Express is absolutely, totally free - so that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your description... if you're going to use the app locally this is the way to go. You need SQL Server on the client machine. It's the only way to get the app up and running.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2005 Express is perfectly fine and to distribute it with your application is perfectly fine too, as it is free and will auto install if you use the click once deployment from Visual Studio.  SQL 2005 Express will have a max database size of 4gb, but if you require more, SQL 2008 and up allow a 10gb database size.